# How to set sound balance through command line?

Tags: command-line, sound

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop. The right (internal) speaker is dead, so I change the sound balance to full left in Ubuntu sound settings everytime I need to play some video/music. At each startup, the sound balance gets forgotten (back on default value).

I would like to write a short shell script that sets the balance to full left (in order to run it at startup). But I can't find the command line.

Does someone knows it ?

Thanks :-)
M3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/317296/setting-audio-balance-from-command-line): If you run PulseAudio then try with alsamixer:

`amixer set Master 100% 0%`.

To automate the process, you can write a Unit for systemd that will run this command on startup.

Comment: Thank you !
That command line doesn't work on my system, but I followed your link and it gives the solution for OS with Pulseaudio :
`amixer -D pulse set Master 100%,0%`
That one works for me.
Have a nice evening ! :-)